# Usage of the word Fellow

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

I've been searching for a word to mean a person who I know quite well, speak with but who hasn't been my friend. My friends are people I trust and can rely on, I have two or three of them. So, I found a word fellow which as I got it can mean it, but still not sure, and also all the examples show it's mostly referred to a male person. 
So the questions is: what's the most widely used word to call a person who I know but who's not my close friend? And can I say a sentence like:

*Oh, I know Marry she's my fellow*    (she's not my colleague, let's say she's just my neighbor and we speak quite often)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single word that refers to what you're describing. You would probably have to use a phrase to make it clear to most American English speakers what you're talking about.

An acquaintance is someone you know, but not too well. I think most people would call the person you're talking about a friend, or a 'casual friend'. To talk about someone who is closer to you than a casual friend you would say you have two or three 'good friends' or 'best friends'. A good friend is someone you trust and know best among all the people you know.

Fellow is not the best term for this. It was more commonly used to refer to a person before the mid-20th century. The phrase, 'my good fellow' was a way of addressing someone in the 19th or early 20th century. By itself it means something like 'comrade', as in 'Robin Hood and his band of merry fellows'. If you say 'my fellow' in the 21st century you are talking about someone who has the same role as another. You would add the role you're talking about:

> my fellow student
>   my fellow lawyer
>   his fellow champion